# Argument of type 'File' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<string>'

Tags: reactjs, react-typescript

I'm building an application using React with typescript, I have a multipart post that works if I initialize to any my 'evt' on the handleImageUpload function.
But if I try to initialize it to React.ChangeEvent gives the following error:

'Argument of type 'File' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction'.'
can you help me to solve this problem?
can you also suggest to me how to change the any initialization of my handleSubmit function?
thank you <3

```
  const handleSubmit = async (evt: any) => {
    // debugger;
    evt.preventDefault();
    setIsProcessingUpload(true);
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('logoimg', logo);
    formData.append('background_image', background);
    formData.append('name', name);

    console.log(formData);
    try {
      Api.post('api/companies', formData, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
      }).finally(() => {
        setIsProcessingUpload(false)
        closeModal();
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

```
  const [logo, setImage] = useState('');

  const handleImageUpload = (evt: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    if (evt.target.files != null) {
      setImage(evt.target.files[0]); //error
    }
  };
```

Comment: I believe this happens because you are declaring useState without a type so it assumes the state to be a string type, hence throwing the error when it receives the file type. When you set evt to any type, it may not be apparent to the compiler that evt.target.files is of File type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about declaring `File` type for your `useState` instead of String `''`;

```
 const [logo, setImage] = useState<File | null>(null);

  const handleImageUpload = (evt: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    if (evt.target.files != null) {
      setImage(evt.target.files[0]); //error
    }
  };
```

Comment: thanks, now it works.
However, I had another error that I solved by changing: 
'useState<File | null>(null);' to 
useState<string | Blob>('');